# hierarchical faceting

Tags: solr, taxonomy

Has anybody have experience implementing hierarchical faceting in this fashion?  See link
http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/multi-level-faceting-td1629650.html#a1672083

What should the schema look like?

(I would like to implement tree faceting without use of SOLR-64.  The patch works well on older branch, the only thing is that it doesn't patch solr trunk.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have experience with the particular solution described in the mailing list post but during my last research into his area I stumbled upon the the [Solr Bobo Browse](http://code.google.com/p/bobo-browse/wiki/SolrIntegration) integration. It also supports hierarchical faceting and seems quite mature.

If you want to stick with the pure Solr solution you would add a single multivalued field to the document for every aspect that you want to facet on. The example in the mailing list assumes that you have just one field called `category`.

In your schema XML you would add:

```
<field name="category" type="string" 
                               indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
```

When you index you documents you would then index all levels of your hierarchy that the document belongs to with the hierarchy level as a prefix:

```
<category>1_sport</category>
<category>2_watersport</category>
<category>3_scuba_diving</category>
```

Querying and traversing the hierarchy once it is indexed is quite well explained in the mailing list.

Comment: well, that is true, I was really just hoping to stay w/in Solr.

Comment: The suggested solution would use plain Solr with bobo as a plugin residing in the `lib` folder and some settings in the `solrxml`. So nothing too intrusive. Definitely less painfull than having a custom patched version of Solr.

Comment: I had not been able to install bobo-browse so far :'(